# How do I play or share a voice memo?

Tags: iphone, ios

[image]

I can't play this voice memo. It won't play. I also can't share it.

iOS 10.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I hear this happens when the app crashes mid-recording. Does it pop up when you try to sync the voice recording with iTunes?

You could try extracting it with a program like [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer). Find it under the 'recordings' folder.